# Swift AlamoFire PUT request

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have a JSON file with this struct:

```
{
   "example": {
        "projects": [
             { "projectname" : "abc",
               "date" : "20200930",}
             { "projectname" : "bac",
               "date" : "20200803",}
        ]
    } 
}
```

I want to update first projectname, but not the date connected to it. But the AF.request method give me back error 400 (Invalid JSON body passed.)

```swift
let user = "username"

let password = "password"
let params = ["example":
        ["projects":
            ["projectname": "New Name"]
        ]
    ]

let credentialData = "\(user):\(password)".data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))!

let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedString()
let headers : HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json" ]

AF.request("https://example.com/api", method: .put, parameters: params, headers: headers).responseJSON { AFdata in
    do {
        guard let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: AFdata.data!) as? [String: Any] else {
            print("Error: Cannot convert data to JSON object")
            return
        }
        guard let prettyJsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: .prettyPrinted) else {
            print("Error: Cannot convert JSON object to Pretty JSON data")
            return
        }
        guard let prettyPrintedJson = String(data: prettyJsonData, encoding: .utf8) else {
            print("Error: Could print JSON in String")
            return
        }

        print(prettyPrintedJson)
    } catch {
        print("Error: Trying to convert JSON data to string")
        return
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `["projectname": "New Name"]` => `[["projectname": "New Name"]]`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing the `encoder` parameter in you request:

```
AF.request("https://example.com/api", method: .put, parameters: params, headers: headers, encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default).responseJSON { AFdata in
```

Without it Alamofire cannot know that your parameters should be encoded as JSON.